# Unity objects certain amount of distance away from the camera's view reappearing on screen?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a long text in the form of 3D mesh that I animated to arrive from the right side of the screen. When non of it is actually in front of the camera's view, from one point of its shape and further right that section gets drawn into the screen coming from the left side, and higher than the object's actual set height.

So if you move an object right enough away from the camera, it comes back into the screen "a row higher" and from the left. It possibly does the opposite when moved far to the left off the screen (returning a row lower and from the right), but I didn't check.

Why does it do that and how can I fix this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have multiple cameras in your project? Could you also add some screenshots or something .. it is a bit hard to imagine what it looks like

Comment: Ah, oops, I made a separate camera for the canvas and it seems the object simply reach it a certain amount of distance off the right of the main camera.

Comment: ;) you might want to work with [Layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) and make the UI camera only render what it should render and wise versa

Comment: Probably. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a small detail I've missed, as suggested by derHugo. I had another camera set aside for the canvas and objects reaching it were drawn onto the screen again.